# Creating a folder from my application to the other application in android

Tags: android, file

I am trying to create a folder in launcher application from the settings application. Is it possible ? I have tried with this `/data/data/com.android.launcher/themes` path. But that time i got exception like this

```
caused by java.lang.illegalargumentexception file contains a path separator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sure you can not create a dir inside /data/data folder if your mobile is not rooted.

Edit: show us how are you trying to create the folder. (post some snippet of code)

Comment: Even then you can not simply create a directory - you have to execute `su mkdir /data/data/com.android.launcher/themes`

Comment: maybe is trying to use getCacheDir() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29 ? It is difficult to say if him does not post some code

Answer (score 0):

The data folder in android is only really accessible by rooted phones and the emulator. Reading and writing may give you problems. If you want to get content from one application to another or something of that sort, Android has it built in. It's called ContentProvider. Read more on it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html